# Structure of student marks

Tags: c++, arrays, function, struct, max

I have defined a `strudent` as:

```
struct student{
    char name[50];
    int roll;
    int marks;
};
```

And I'm trying to print the `student` in `s` who has the highest `marks` field:

```
struct student s[5];
int i;

cout << "Enter information of students : " << endl;

for(i=0;i<3;++i)
{
    cout <<"Enter roll no : ";
    cin>>s[i].roll;
    cout << "Enter name : ";
    cin >> s[i].name;
    cout << endl << "Enter marks : ";
    cin >> s[i].marks;
    cout << endl;
}

for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
{

    if(s[j].marks>60)
    {
        cout<<s[j].roll<<"  "<<s[j].name<<" = "<<s[j].marks<<" is Passed"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<s[j].roll<<" "<<s[j].name<<" = "<<s[j].marks<<" is Failed"<< endl;
    }
}

cout<<endl;
cout<<endl;
int max=s[0].marks;

for(int k=0; k<3; k++)
{
    if(s[k].marks>max)
    {
        max=s[k].marks;
    }

    cout<<s[k].roll<<" "<<s[k].name<<" "<<max<<" is top in the class:"<<endl;

}
```

Right now my prints all the students! I just want the name and roll no of the student who has top marks among all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: actually I'm not sharing it with anyone else, this code does not show the roll of individual who has maximum marks.

Comment: Your `max` implementation is wrong! You have to find the max marks and _remember_ the `k` value for it. After your `for` loop is completed you `cout<<s[max_index],roll ....`

Answer (score 1):

You say you: **Want the name and roll of the student who has top marks among all the students**

To get that you need to find the *index* of the student with the highest marks. But before I give you an example of how to do that, I'll need the whole `s` array to be initialized. This means:

- Your initialization loop needs to run the size of your array (`for(i = 0; i < sizeof(s) / sizeof(s[0]); ++i)`)
- Or your array size needs to match your loop (`student s[3]`)

Once that's done you can effectively use [`max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) to find your student with the top marks:

```
const auto it = max_element(cbegin(s), cend(s), [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs){ return lhs.marks < rhs.marks; });
```

`it` now points to your student with the highest marks, you can print it like this:

```
cout << it->roll << ' ' << it->name << ' ' << it->marks << " is top in the class\n";
```

You can see a live example of this here: http://ideone.com/JcPQMI